# jarsigner keystore error

Tags: java, keytool, jarsigner

I created a key to java program with the keytool command:

```
keytool –genkey –alias chave –validity 10000 –keypass 000005 –keystore “c:\Documents\chave\chave” –storepass 000005;
```

Then, I sign with the command:

```
jarsigner –keypass 000005 –storepass 000005 –keystore “c:\Documents\chave\chave” “c:\Projeto\Autenticacao\Autenticacao\dist\Autenticacao.jar” chave;
```

But is occurring the following error:

```
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystone load: keystore was tampared with, or password was incorrect.
```

I can not understand what is wrong.